# How to delete a file from multiple zip archives using 7-Zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a thousand zip archives that all contain a file I want to remove. I can get 7Zip to remove them one file at a time from the command line:

```
7z d -r archive.zip *.pdf
```

but how would I apply that across all the files, which are themselves grouped in sub-directories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /r %v in (*.zip) do 7z d -r "%v" *.pdf
```

But no idea if it's working, just wrote out of my head :P

Comment: Brilliant, minor change to this
    `for /r %v in (*.zip) do 7z d -r %v *.pdf`
and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.zip') DO 7z.exe d -r %%G *.pdf
```

This works almost in the same way as the accepted answer. Only the way how the files are gathered is different. Whereas the answer above uses `for /r` to run through all directories and subdirectories, this one parses the output of the command `dir /b *.zip` to get all the files relevant.
The 7zip command remains the same and only the parameters are changed.

Note: To run this outside of a batchfile replace `%%G` with `%G`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, add a bit of explanation for future readers :-)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes simple things can solve the problems...

do the following to delete any file / all file from selected .zip files>

1. Move the .zip files to a new folder
2. Select all the files from which files to be deleted
3. right click and select option "extract each archive to separate folder"
4. all the zip files shall be converted to folder now.
5. use and file search tool like SearchMyFiles and find required files, select and delete.
6. convert the folders back to .zip